# Why does my string.strip() function in python fails to strip other characters along the same line?

Tags: python

For instance, I have this:

```
stra = "this is stringt exampltte....wow! !!0000000"
print stra.strip('t')
```

> his is stringt exampltte....wow! !!0000000

why does the function only strip the first 't'?

In contrast, we have this:
    stra = "000000this is stringt exampltte....wow! !!0000000"
    print stra.strip('0')

> this is stringt exampltte....wow! !!

which strips all of the '0'. Why would this remove all '0' in this case but not in the case of 't'?

Third variation, we have this:

```
stra = "000000this is stringt exampltte....wow! !!0000000"
print stra.strip('this')
```

> 000000this is stringt exampltte....wow! !!0000000

Which removes nothing at all! Not even in the words that have t,h,i,s in it. But if we were to remove the zeros from the start,

```
stra = "this is stringt exampltte....wow! !!0000000"
print stra.strip('this')
```

> is stringt exampltte....wow! !!0000000

It seems that the strip function in my python 2.7.x only works for the first combination of characters separated by whitespace, or for only number strings! Why is this so?

Comment: How very strange! Maybe it's because that's what `strip` is supposed to do. You should Google it and read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.strip()`, as stated by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> **str.strip([chars])**
>
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.

What does this mean? It will remove all possible combinations of the `chars` you pass as parameter, but only if it's **leading** or **trailing** the string.

So, for example:

```
'hello John, llohe'.strip('helo')
```

Will leave you with:

```
' John, '
```

But:

```
'0hello John, llohe0'.strip('helo')
```

Will leave the string unaltered. Here the possible combinations of `h,e,l,o` aren't leading or trailing the string.

Answer (score 1):

The `strip()` function works like `trim()` in JavaScript, removing white-space from the start and end of a string.

But it has a plus! It can receive a parameter to change the characters to remove.

It does not remove all the occurrences of the character from the string. It only removes from the start and end of the string.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Official Documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) of `string.strip`.

To explain quick, strip removed characters at the beginning of the string or the end of the string or both. If the character is inside it will not be removed. If the character you are stripping is repeated on each end, all the repetitions will be removed.

Comment: Not sure you why you are being downvoted on this. This is short and to the point

Comment: @mmenschig copy / paste of documentation without any good explaination isn't worth reading :P

Comment: @Alvaro there is no copy & paste of documentation on this. I provided the link (so did you) and it ends there. I provided a short explanation of strip without having to write examples because the OP wrote examples. Unless my explanation was misleading or wrong, you would downvote me and I can change or remove my post after knowing that its misleading. If you feel like your post is better than mine, let viewers judge for themselves rather than bringing other posts down except yours.